# Accessing internet behind proxy in headless Ubuntu where proxy requires login through browser

Tags: networking, ubuntu, browser, proxy

I access internet in my campus through auto configuration proxy url (format: https://proxyXY.CAMPUS.DOMAIN/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi) which opens a login page on broswer and after logging in, I can access Internet on other non-browser applications by setting a proxy server (format: 10.XX.YY.ZZ:PORT#) in the application settings. This works as long as I am logged-in in the browser.

Now, I am working on a headless Ubuntu, which has internet connectivity through Ethernet LAN. I have done these proxy settings in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/05proxy:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://myUserName:myPwd@proxyXY.CAMPUS.DOMAIN:PORT#";
```

When I run apt-get update, I get:

```
Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I think this is probably because I have not provided authentication through the web browser. Is there any way to log in to the proxy server without using browser/user interface?

Comment: I have tried with Acquire::http:Proxy "http://myUserName:myPwd@10.XX.YY.ZZ:PORT#" also, but I get the same output.

Also, I have tried both http and https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to achieve the same thing. I have found an article at https://blog.apify.com/how-to-make-headless-chrome-and-puppeteer-use-a-proxy-server-with-authentication-249a21a79212
which helps somewhat.

**The user:password@... part is not supported anymore. It is a security risk.**

**They use a proxy chain instead.**

As it mentions the --proxy-server=... doesn't work in Chrome, only in Chromium. So they create a **Squid** proxy chain with **cache_peer** directive. They use the following config file to set user and password:

```
http_port 3128
cache_peer proxy.example.com parent 8000 0 \
  no-query \
  login=bob:password123 \
  connect-fail-limit=99999999 \
  proxy-only \
  name=my_peer
cache_peer_access my_peer allow all
```

Then they run it like this:

```
squid -f squid.conf -N
```

But that was for an older version of Squid. Probably Squid 2. They also say: "The Squid processes would spontaneously hang or not start at all, each platform behaved differently, etc." I haven't tested if that changed with latest versions.

**They also offer a node.js based [proxy-chain](https://github.com/apifytech/proxy-chain) pack on github which might help.**

Let me know if that works for you or what other solution you find.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! At first, I did not understand much how this proxy chaining would work, so I left it after a few tries. I tried it again today and it worked. I installed squid on my system which has desktop manager installed. This served as parent. Added these lines in squid.conf:
cache_peer <proxy.example.com> parent 3128 0 no-query default
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
never_direct allow all
http_access allow all
And on the other system, which is headless, added these lines in apt.conf.d/proxy.conf:
Acquire::http::Proxy "ip_of_parent:3128"
Acquire::https::Proxy "ip_of_parent:3128"

Comment: Another method that I found was, installing a command line browser, like elinks. This also worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I like elinks but it has news from 2012. How does it work now with js? Did you try it with latest websites?

Comment: My primary purpose for trying elinks was to be able to login to proxy authentication page. So I did not try to load other websites. Also, I am not much familiar with JavaScript, so I cannot say how elinks works with JS. My apologies. Though a little search on Google says elinks is the only text mode browser which supports JS.